# Abstract nonsense proof of the cocompleteness of the category of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

There is a well-known way to conclude the cocompleteness of a category from its completeness. Namely, if a category is complete, well-powered and has a cogenerating set, then it is cocomplete (easy corollary of the special adjoint functor theorem).

I was hoping I could use this to prove that the category $\mathbf{Grp}$ of groups is cocomplete. I would find it interesting, for completeness of $\mathbf{Grp}$ is easy to prove (the forgetful functor to the category of sets creates limits), while cocompletenes is not so easy (constructing free product is quite tedious).

But alas, a quick google search revealed that $\mathbf{Grp}$ doesn't have a cogenerator (it can be read off the only freely available page of [this article](http://www.springerlink.com/content/tm5hw23095367605/)). I suspect it doesn't have a cogenerating *set*, either.

Is there a categorical proof of the cocompleteness of $\mathbf{Grp}$?

Edit: I'd like to point out that I found out afterwards the following exercise 1 in section IX.1 of Mac Lane's CWM (I didn't expect to find this exercise in the chapter on "Special Limits"!)

> Use the adjoint functor theorem to prove in one step that Grp has all small colimits.

Comment: $\text{Grp}$ doesn't have a cogenerating set because there are simple groups of arbitrarily large cardinality (see for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32908/three-questions-on-large-simple-groups-and-model-theory).

Comment: Why not use the _general_ adjoint functor theorem? I think the cardinality trick works for $[\mathcal{J}, \textbf{Grp}]$.

Comment: [Here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimits+in+categories+of+algebras) is a general nonsense proof that the category of algebras for a monad on $\textbf{Set}$ is cocomplete.

Comment: @Zhen Lin, shouldn't you just put that nLab link into an answer?

Comment: @Qiaochu: how does it follow from that fact?

Comment: @Bruno: if $G_i$ is a set-indexed family of groups, find a simple group $H$ of cardinality larger than $\bigcup G_i$. Then there is no nonzero map from $H$ to any of the $G_i$, so $G_i$ is not a cogenerating set.

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` seems to be broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a proof using the general adjoint functor theorem is closest in spirit to a general nonsense proof, but it involves some rather concrete arguments about cardinality!

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be a small category, and let $\Delta : \textbf{Grp} \to [\mathcal{J}, \textbf{Grp}]$ be the "diagonal" functor. $\textbf{Grp}$ has colimits of shape $\mathcal{J}$ if and only if this functor $\Delta$ has a left adjoint (provided we assume a sufficiently large axiom of choice, or be careful about defining what we mean by "has colimits of shape $\mathcal{J}$"). Now recall the general adjoint functor theorem: when $\mathcal{D}$ is complete and locally small, a functor $U : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ has a left adjoint if and only if, for each object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the comma category $(X \downarrow U)$ has a small weakly initial family (a.k.a. a solution set). So, for $U = \Delta$ and a diagram $X : \mathcal{J} \to \textbf{Grp}$, we must find a small set of groups such that every cocone on $X$ factors through one of those groups. But this is easy enough to arrange: let $\kappa$ be the cardinality of the disjoint union of all the groups $X_j$; then there is only a set of isomorphism classes of groups generated by $\kappa$ or fewer elements. (To be very concrete about it, we could say "the set of all groups whose underlying set is a subset of $\aleph_0 \cdot \kappa$".)

On the other hand, the above proof is morally appealing to the existence of coproducts in $\textbf{Grp}$, or at least free groups on arbitrarily many generators. So maybe it would be better to use a more direct argument. [This nLab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimits+in+categories+of+algebras) sketches a proof that the category of algebras for a monad on $\textbf{Set}$ is always cocomplete; one then uses the fact that $\textbf{Grp}$ is monadic over $\textbf{Set}$ to conclude that $\textbf{Grp}$ is cocomplete.

Comment: Thanks, Zhen Lin! I'm not familiar with algebras for a monad, but the first proof using GAFT was very useful. I'll post my own writeup of the proof with some more detail in a little while.

Answer (score 3):

Zhen Lin already sketched a proof of the cocompleteness of $\mathbf{Grp}$ using the general adjoint functor theorem. Here's how I filled up the details.

Let $J$ be a small category; we wish to show the diagonal functor $\Delta:\mathbf{Grp}\to \mathbf{Grp}^J$ has a left adjoint. The diagonal functor preserves limits (direct consequence of the pointwise construction of limits in $\mathbf{Grp}^J$) and $\mathbf{Grp}$ is complete, so it suffices to check the solution set condition.

Let $D\in \mathbf{Grp}^J$ be a diagram. We note $D_j:=Dj$ for all $j\in J$.

Consider the class consisting of groups of cardinality $\aleph_0$ and of groups of cardinality $\leq \lvert \bigsqcup\limits_{j\in J} D_j \rvert$ for all $j\in J$. We consider the *set* $\{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ of groups consisting of one isomorphism class per each of these groups.

I claim the *set* of all natural transformations $\{D\Rightarrow \Delta G_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ is a solution set.

Fix $\varphi:D\Rightarrow \Delta G$. We must check that there exists $\alpha\in \Lambda$, $\tau^\alpha:D\Rightarrow \Delta G_\alpha$ in the solution set and $t:G_\alpha\to G$ a group homomorphism such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

Remember that natural transformations $D\Rightarrow \Delta K$ are exactly cocones for the diagram $D$ with vertex $K$.

So, to put it differently, we must find a cocone morphism between some cocone $\tau^\alpha$ in the solution set and the fixed cocone $\varphi$, i.e. a group morphism $t:G\alpha\to G$ such that the following diagram commutes for every arrow $e^i_j:i\to j$ of $J$:

[image]

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\bigsqcup\limits_{i\in J} \operatorname{Im} \varphi_j$. Then $H=G_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in \Lambda$ (by the same argument used in the proof that there exist free groups using GAFT).

We define $\tau^\alpha_i:D_i\to G_\alpha$ as $\tau^\alpha_i(x)=(\varphi_i(x),i)$ for every $i\in J$. So $\tau^\alpha:D\Rightarrow \Delta G_\alpha$ is a cocone for $D$: this is quickly verified using the fact that $\varphi$ is already a cocone.

Now we define $t:G_\alpha\to G$ as $t(\varphi_i(x),i)=\varphi_i(x)$; clearly $t\circ \tau^\alpha_i=\varphi_i$ for all $i\in J$, thus finishing the proof.