# Pushout of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup and $\iota: H\to G$ the inclusion map. What is the "pushout along $\iota$? How is it constructed?

Comment: Where did you see the term? There are two few maps here to make an obvious pushout diagram (which would involve two maps from $H$).

Comment: I am pretty certain the to maps are twice the inclusion $\iota:H\to G$.. If that's the case, what would then the pushout diagram / construction look like?

Comment: I am not actually sure the pushout exists in general (since the groups are not assumed abelian). If they were abelian then it would be the quotient of $G\times G$ by the subgroup consisting of elements $(h,0)-(0,h)$ for $h\in H$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Isn't the category of groups cocomplete? See eg. [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180477/abstract-nonsense-proof-of-the-cocompleteness-of-the-category-of-groups).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Ahh, right. So I guess it will be the quotient of the free product by the normal subgroup generated by those relations.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Besides, even if the groups are abelian, the pushout in the category of groups and the pushout in the category of abelian groups is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the pushout of this diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H @>{\iota}>> G \\
@V{\iota}VV \\
G
\end{CD}$$
It's possible to describe it "explicitly": it is the quotient of the free product $G * G$ by the normal subgroup $N$ generated by the relations $\iota_1(h) \equiv \iota_2(h)$ where $\iota_1$ is the inclusion of $H$ in the first factor of $G*G$ and $\iota_2$ the inclusion in the second factor. It is typically denoted by:
$$G *_H G = G * G / \langle \iota_1(h) \equiv \iota_2(h) \rangle.$$

This is a rather badly behaved group. For example if $G = \mathbb{Z}$, $H = 2\mathbb{Z}$, then the group $G$ you get has a presentation given by $\langle x,y \mid x^2 = y^2 \rangle$. It's not a very nice group. I doubt you can say much more than that.

Two extreme examples: if $H = \{e\}$, then $G *_{\{e\}} G = G * G$ is the free product of $G$ with itself. If $H = G$, then $G *_G G$ is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: hey I was wondering can you say if we can inject $H$ into the group with presentation $<x,y : x^2 = y^2>$?

Answer (score 0):

Pushouts (and colimits in general) can always be constructed from coproducts and coequalizers whenever these are available (see Awodey's text on category theory, for example). So the pushout of an arrow $ H \to K$ along along the inclusion $H \hookrightarrow G$ would be the quotient of the coproduct of $G$ and $K$ by the appropriate equivalence relation. Just draw out the coproduct diagram and you'll see what the [coequalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer) should be.

I haven't ever personally come across a pushout of groups, so I'm not sure what the usual "interpretation" of this object is, but this is most likely the easiest way it would be constructed.

Comment: Can you give a concrete construction..? I'm not familiar with coequalisers (but thanks for the link)